# Generar una cadena de numeros aleatorios con una longitud determinada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quería saber como podría crear una cadena de números aleatorios introduciéndole yo la longitud que debe tener dicha cadena.

Por ejemplo, que el programa me genere una lista entre 1 y 9 y tenga una longitud de 3 caracteres. Gracias.

Comment: Hola oskr ¿Has intentado algo? Mírate el módulo [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), tiene lo que necesitas. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo he visto, gracias @FJSevilla, habia visto algunas funciones de random pero no la de random.choices()

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien sería algo así:

```
import random

result = []

for x in range(0,3):
    result.append(random.randint(0,9))

print result
```

El resultado es el siguiente (podrían haber sido otros números):

```
[0, 5, 8]
```

Cada vez que ejecutes el script te va a dar un resultado diferente. Espero que te haya servido. Un saludo!!

Comment: Creo que la lista era conformada por 9 elementos y cada elemento de 3 caracteres númericos o bueno eso fue lo que entendí de la explicación del OP

Comment: @Huskie yo he entendido una lista de 3 elementos que sea random entre 1-9. Si no es así que lo aclare un poquito.

Comment: Lo siento si me he explicado mal, yo lo que quiero es crear un numero de 3 cifras, utilizando 2 numeros, como por ejemplo 2 y el 4, y que me diese de resultado 424. Espero que sea mas claro ahora.

Comment: @FranMoya Si yo entendí lo mismo pero por los comentarios del OP me di cuenta que ni tu ni yo entendimos bien xD!

Comment: De hecho tenía una respuesta según lo que le entendí y tampoco iba a servirle jaja

Comment: @oskr uff, creo que te has explicado bastante mal porque ninguno lo habíamos entendido jejejeje. Ya te han dado una respuesta que es válida, un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bien sencilla, es usar `random.choice()` que obtiene un valor al azar de una lista determinada:

```
import random

valores = [2,4]
size = 3

random.seed(5) # Esto solo para hacer reproducible el ejemplo

print("".join([str(random.choice(valores)) for i in range(size)]))
442
```

Detalles:

- `random.seed(5)` lo puedes eliminar, es solo para establecer la semilla inicial, y hacer reproducible el ejemplo, de esta forma si corres el código el resultado será el mismo que yo obtengo.
- Definimos `valores` con la lista de valores de los que queremos obtener cada parte de la cadena y el tamaño de la misma en `size`
- Usamos una comprensión de listas para generar en primer lugar una lista de cadenas de tamaño `size`: `[str(random.choice(valores)) for _ in range(size)]`
- Usamos el método `join()` que tiene cada cadena, para concatenar una lista